# This client-server minigame won't restart itself

Tags: c, server, client, client-server

A friend and I have completed a client-server minigame in the C language for an exam on Unix advanced programming. We are setting an `alarm()` and when this guy finishes, we capture it with `signal()` and we've made a function to read such signal and restart the server. But what happens all the time is that the server closes but gives the following error: `["bind error in server" : Address already in use].`

We've tried to give it a `sleep()`, but the error keeps coming up.
PS: The entire mini-game works, even with up to 10 clients.
Here is partial code:

```
void restartServerAlarm(int numSegnale){
printf("Riavvio del server in corso...\n");
unlink("localhost");
close(s_fd);

/Deallocamento mutex usati/
deallocaMutexs();

/Deallocamento di tutti i giocatori/
eliminaGiocatori(giocatori,posizioneGiocatori);
//Tutte le altre strutture sono statiche

sleep(10);

execl("./start.sh",0);
perror("Errore nel restarting del server.\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

"Nuova Connessione = New connection"
Start.sh is a simple script containing "./server.out"

```
while (1)
{
    c_fd = malloc(sizeof(int));
    client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    if ((c_fd = accept(s_fd, (struct sockaddr)&client_addr, &client_len)) < 0)
        perror("accept error nel server \a\n"), exit(1);
    printf("Server: Nuova connessione da [%d] \n", *c_fd);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, handle, (void *)c_fd);
    pthread_detach(tid);

    serverLog(inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));

}

How i start the server right now :
  /*Accensione del server*/
if ((s_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    perror("socket error nel server\a\n"), exit(1);
if (setsockopt(s_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)
error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
if (bind(s_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0)
    perror("bind error nel server \a\n"), exit(1);
if (listen(s_fd, 15) < 0) // Il socket si mette in ascolto
    perror("listen error nel server \a\n"), exit(1)
```

Comment: regarding: `execl("./start.sh",0);`  I would expect this to be: `execl( "./start.sh", "start.sh", NULL );`

Comment: since you want the alarm handling code to always be available, Why isn't there a call to `fork()` then in the resulting child code, making the call to `execl()`?

Answer (score 0):

after generating the socket, need to call the function to modify the socket so it is reusable.

suggest something similar to:

```
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this function didn't do the trick, but thanks anyways !

Comment: The function: `setsockopt()` has to be in the `server.c` file, right after `sock_t sockfd = socket( .... );`

Comment: Yes, that's how i had updated it, i've added the part on the main code up here.